# Como passar a PDO para outros objetos em aplicação MVC OOP

Tags: php, orientação-a-objetos

Estou desenvolvendo um pequeno framework para fins de aprendizagem, e uma das formas que encontrei de passar o objeto PDO para ser usado nos controllers/models foi usando a seguinte abordagem:

> O método construtor do Controller pai recebe um objeto PDO, e este é
>   herdado por todos os "Controllers filhos", que também herdam o
>   método "loadModel", que retorna um objeto já com o PDO que foi passado como argumento no Controller pai.

.

**DÚVIDA**: Esta é uma boa abordagem? senão, por que? quais as vantagens e desvantages? e qual seria uma boa alternativa?

**COMPLEMENTO:** fiz algumas pesquisas e parece que o pattern apropriado para isso seria o Factory, mas não sei como seria sua implementação no meu código de modo que fique disponível para todos os controllers, mesmo os que não utilizem conexão com o banco de dados.

Se possível, exemplificar baseado no meu código

**connection.php**

```
<?php

$options = array(
    PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES => false,
    PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION,
    PDO::ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE => PDO::FETCH_ASSOC,
    PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_FOUND_ROWS => true
    );

$connection = new PDO('mysql:host='.DB_HOST.';dbname='.DB_NAME.';charset='. DB_CHARSET, DB_USER, DB_PASS, $options);

return $connection;
```

**index.php**

> // possui algumas validações e tratamento de URLs de rotas (controller -
>   action) e define o controller na variável $controller, e este recebe,
>   através do construtor, o objeto PDO para ser usado dentro do método.

```
$obj = new $controller($connection);
```

**controller.php (Controller pai)**

```
class Controller {

private $connection;

function __construct ($connection) {
    $this->connection = $connection;
}

public function loadModel ($model) {
    return new $model($this->connection);
}
```

**UserController.php (controller de exemplo)**

```
class UserController extends Controller {

    function registration () {

            $useCRUD = $this->loadModel('userCRUD');

            $info = array('name' => 'Joao', 'age' => 25);

            $userCRUD->create($info);
        }

}
```

**userCRUD.php**
Recebe pelo construtor o objeto PDO e faz as interações CRUD com o banco de dados.

Comment: Por que você não usa o padrão Singleton? Ele garante apenas uma instância de uma classe, que, no caso seria a sua conexão com o banco. Assim não precisaria de toda essa estrutura.

Comment: Mas o singleton não é um "anti-padrão"?

Answer (score 1):

#### Criando os controllers

Factorys podem ser utilizadas para resolver o problema, para isso elas serão passadas para uma classe que irá executar os controllers verificando se existe alguma factory para sua criação.

A implementação da factory ficaria mais ou menos assim:

```
class UserControllerFactory
{
    // OBS: O método __invoke faz uma classe poder ser executada como uma função do PHP.
    public function __invoke()
    {    
         $userCrud = new UserCrud(PDOFactory::create());
         return new UserController($userCrud);
    }
}
```

Já a classe que irá executar seus controllers seria assim:

```
class ControllerInitializer
{

    private $factorys;

    public function __construct(
        array $factorys
    ){

        $this->factorys = $factorys;

    }

    public function init($controller, $action)
    {

        if(isset($this->factorys[$controller])){
             $factory    = $this->factorys[$controller];
             $controller = $factory();
             $controller->$action();
        }else{
            // Caso o controller não seja encontrado é um erro 404.
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: Acho que agora deu uma clareada, só não entendi muito bem o uso do __invoke(), e além da UserControllerFactory eu teria outra UserController ou poderia já usa-la de forma normal? com os métodos registration etc, e dentro desses métodos teria que abrir uma PDOFactory também?

Comment: e aproveitando o comentário acima do @João Pedro, uma solução poderia ser passar o PDO usando singleton? diretamente na chamada do model, por exemplo: `$userModel = new userModel(PDOFactory::getInstance());`